# How to hide cursor line when focus in on other window in vim

Tags: vim

In my vimrc file i have this option `set cursorline`. I want to hide this line if that window is not in focus . Is there an option in vim to do that? 
See this [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially, it's just the following autocmds:

```
augroup CursorLine
    au!
    au VimEnter * setlocal cursorline
    au WinEnter * setlocal cursorline
    au BufWinEnter * setlocal cursorline
    au WinLeave * setlocal nocursorline
augroup END
```

But occasionally, you may want to define exceptions (i.e. permanently on or off) for certain windows. That's where my [CursorLineCurrentWindow plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4178) may be helpful.

Comment: i just put your plugin in my bundle folder.But its not getting loaded .how should i load it? I am using Pathogen to load all plugins

Comment: You still need to `:set cursorline` in your `.vimrc` before the plugin is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the cursorline on when entering a vim buffer and off when leaving it.  These commands in the vimrc file will achieve this:

```
autocmd BufEnter * set cursorline
autocmd BufLeave * set nocursorline
```

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted , thanks! But when i open a new buffer i can still see the cursor line on prev buffer.

Comment: The autocmds aren't right; see my answer for something that works.

Comment: Agree.  Ingo's answer is better.